# Delete data off USB

Tags: usb-drive, delete

There seems to be an annoying setting somewhere that goes like this. I copy some video files to a 1gb USB thumb drive, after watching the videos else where, I come back to Ubuntu and delete the video files from the USB thumb drive. However after doing this a few times I realize that although I don't see anything in the file manager, in fact the drive is full. To actually allow the system to write new files to the drive I then use gparted to reformat the USB thumb drive. Is there a way to make it actually count the data that I delete at free space on the thumb drive? Or am I missing something all together?

Answer (score 1):

> Or am I missing something all together?

In general when I disconnect a flash drive it prompts to ask to empty trash. Those files of yours are probably 'moved' to the recyle bin (to a directory named .Trash).

A method to not use the Trash is to delete with <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>delete</kbd> (and it is also an easy way to check if this is the case).

Comment: That sounds very reasonable, I will check it out later. thanks!